# Applications of Hausdorff's Formula

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I'm curious about the importance and applications of the Hausdorff's Formula:
$$\aleph_{\alpha+1}^{\aleph_\beta}=\aleph_{\alpha}^{\aleph_\beta}.\aleph_{\alpha+1}$$
What are its implications? Where can I use it?

I was wondering if it's used to prove some important result, or if there is some paper about it.

Comment: That seems like an odd question. Where can you use it? In situations where you have $\aleph_{\alpha+1}^{\aleph_\beta}$.

Comment: But does it have some important implications? Is it used to prove some important result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer to your question could be just as generalistic as your question itself really is.

The Hausdorff recursion formula builds the fundament of what Hausdorff himself nominated as ***confinality*** and subsequently ***every other result*** that deducted versus ***Aleph exponentaition***.

Historically favorable, would suggest you start the journey with his own symphony "H.: Gesammelte Werke. Band II: Grundzüge der Mengenlehre. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, Heidelberg". There should be perhaps an English version.

---

To your question in comment, tha answer is yes and the list is long. The latest I am aware of, is the recursive formula of Silver in: J. Silver, "On the singular cardinals problem" R. James (ed.) , Proc. Internat. Congress Mathematicians (Vancouver, 1974) , 1 , Canad. Math. Congress (1975) pp. 265–268

The simplest deduction should be the well known Bernshtein formula.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I will take a look at this material :)